# How to modify the data I got from promises and return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to make an external module outside my `index.js` to make the code more manageable. However, it does not return what I wanted.

Here's my code in `index.js`

```
app.post('/resumes', authenticate, (req, res) => {

    var body = _.pick(req.body, ['url']);
    var url = body.url;
    request(url)
    .then(function(html){
        //success!
        html = html.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
        html = html.replace(/\t/g, '');
        html = html.replace(/\n/g, '');

        scrape.searchJob(req.user._id, html).then(jobs => {
            res.status(200).send(jobs);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        res.status(400).send({err});
    });
});
```

Here's the `scrape.js`:

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var {Job} = require('../models/job');

var searchJob = ( id, html) => {
    var promise = Job.find({_creator: id}).exec(function (err, jobs){
        jobs.map((job) => {
            job.butter = 'butter';
        });
    });
return promise;
};

module.exports = {searchJob};
```

I'm trying to do some modification the `jobs` that I got from `Job` (mongoose model), yet it still only returns the original data.

I did require `scrape.js` in `index.js`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Quite a few more problems in the code than just the linked duplicate, but it's a start. `Job.find({ ... }).then(jobs => { return jobs })` is basically wrong. As is `console.log('B: ', scrape.searchJob(req.user._id, html))` You don't return values from Promises like that. Even `var {Job} = require('../models/job')` looks suspect here and is more than likely meant to be `var Job = require('../models/job')` unless for some reason you are doing `module.exports.Job = mongoose.model('Job', ...)` elsewhere. But pay attention to working with Promise resolving first.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the comment and the link to the previous question. I'll read the other post to see how I should adjust this!